# How does HTML5 support RDFa?

Tags: html, xhtml, rdfa

I like to publish contont in both RDF format and HTML formats.  So, there is a specific encoding for HTML with RDFa.   Yet there are so many benefits to HTML5 that I like.   But there is no mechanism for specifying RDFa within HTML5.  Are there any solutions to this problem?
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://dev.w3.org/html5/rdfa/